# How to add another page under the main page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to make a page that scrolls down to another page on a click on a div. While I know how to make a page scroll on a click, I completely do not know how to add this "subpage" below mainpage. I though about making the html document longer, and inserting it all into index.html or making completely another page.

Here's the code of the page: http://pastebin.com/1HnhhkFw

Comment: Ok I think I understood, you want to extend this page.. u can do that with "fixed" in css.

Comment: from what I understand is that you want a main DIV which takes 100% width and height and on a click of a button/DIV, make the page scroll to a container underneath. is that it? [Like this example (click the arrow for scroll)](http://www.guestd.com/)

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's what i want

Comment: I guess now the questions are: do you want to use a jquery plugin that already exist to achieve this or do you want to learn how to do it? Most the times, it's best not to reinvent the wheel, as they say, to save time. but it's for you to decide.

Comment: Jquery plugin sounds good to me.

Comment: here, [try this out](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)